# phpとmysqlで画像アップロードのサイトを作っているのですが・・・

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

php,mysqlについて初心の者です。
タイトルにもある通り現在phpとmysqlを使って画像アップロードページを作成しているのですがうまくいきません。
直接mysqlにバイナリデータを登録するのはよろしくないということだったのでサーバー上にフォルダーを作りそこに画像を保存してそのパスをデータとして格納するということにしました。
現段階でDBにはパスを登録できている段階なのですがそれを次は写真アルバムみたいに一覧表示したいと考えてプログラムを書いたのですが表示されません。
ご教授の方よろしくお願いします！

```
<?php

function connect_db()
{
    $dsn = 'mysql:localhost=xxxx;dbname=xxxx;charset=utf8';
    $username = 'xxxx';
    $password = 'xxxx';
    $options = 
    [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        , PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    ];
    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}

function insert($sql, $arr = [])
{
    $pdo = connect_db();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($arr);
    return $pdo->lastInsertId();
}

function select($sql, $arr = [])
{
    $pdo = connect_db();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($arr);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

function h($string)
{
    return htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
}
```

```css
<?php

require 'common.php';

try 
{
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id');

    echo $id;
    // データベースからレコードを取得

    $sql = "SELECT id, title, img_path FROM images WHERE id = :id";
    $arr = [];
    $arr[':id'] = $id;
    $rows = select($sql, $arr);
    $row = reset($rows);

} catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .error {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <?php if (isset($error)) : ?>
                <p class="error"><?= h($error); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <p><?= h($row['title']); ?></p>
            <p>
                <img src="<?= h($row['img_path']); ?>" alt="<?= h($row['title']); ?>" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php

require 'common.php';

function file_upload()
{
    // POSTではないとき何もしない
    if (filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') !== 'POST') 
    {
        return;
    }

    // タイトル
    $title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title');
    if ('' === $title) {
        throw new Exception('タイトルは入力必須です。');
    }

    // アップロードファイル
    $upfile = $_FILES['upfile'];

    if ($upfile['error'] > 0) {
        throw new Exception('ファイルアップロードに失敗しました。');
    }

    $tmp_name = $upfile['tmp_name'];

    // ファイルタイプチェック
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $tmp_name);

    // 許可するMIMETYPE
    $allowed_types = [
        'jpg' => 'image/jpeg'
        , 'png' => 'image/png'
        , 'gif' => 'image/gif'
    ];
    if (!in_array($mimetype, $allowed_types)) {
        throw new Exception('許可されていないファイルタイプです。');
    }

    // ファイル名（ハッシュ値でファイル名を決定するため、同一ファイルは同盟で上書きされる）
    $filename = sha1_file($tmp_name);

    // 拡張子
    $ext = array_search($mimetype, $allowed_types);

    // 保存作ファイルパス
    $destination = sprintf('%s/%s.%s'
        , 'upfiles'
        , $filename
        , $ext
    );

    echo $destination;

    // アップロードディレクトリに移動
    if (!move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $destination)) 
    {
        throw new Exception('ファイルの保存に失敗しました。');
    }

    // データベースに登録
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `images` (`id`, `title`, `img_path`) VALUES (NULL, :title, :img_path) ';
    $arr = [];
    $arr[':title'] = $title;
    $arr[':img_path'] = $destination;
    echo $title ;
    $lastInsertId = insert($sql, $arr);

    // 成功時にページを移動する
    header(sprintf('Location: image.php?id=%d', $lastInsertId));
}

try {
    // ファイルアップロード
    file_upload();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .error {
                color: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <?php if (isset($error)) : ?>
                <p class="error"><?= h($error); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <p>
                    <label for="title">タイトル</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="upfile">画像ファイル</label>
                    <input type="file" name="upfile" id="upfile" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <button type="submit">送信</button>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/112445

Answer (score 1):

複数の結果を取り出すなら以下の様なスクリプトになります。(ぐるぐる回さないと)

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test;charset=utf8','root','root', array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false));

    foreach ( $pdo->query ( 'select * from test' ) as $row ) {
        echo $row['imgname'].'<br>';
    }
//    fetchで回すなら
//    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM test");
//    while($row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
//        echo $row['imgname'].'<br>';
//    }

//プリペアドステートメントの例
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM test where test = ?");
    if ($stmt->execute(array('test1'))) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
            echo '<img src="'.$row['img_path'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].'" />';
        }
    }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('error!'.$e->getMessage());
}

$pdo = null;// 切断
```

Comment: 複数の結果が返るようになったのですが、今の段階だとパスの表示しかできてないのですがそれを画像表示したいのですがどうすればいいですかね？

Comment: 画像が表示したければ　echo "<img src=\"{$row['img_path']}\" alt=\"{$row['title']}\" />";　か　echo '<img src="'.$row['img_path'].'" alt="'.$row['title'].'" />';　の様にimgタグを出力すれば良いです。
phpについては、http://php.net/manual/ja/intro-whatis.php　を　htmlについては、 https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element　を見て理解を深めて下さい。

Comment: imgタグを使い出力できたのですがデータベースに入っている最後の画像がデータの数だけ出力されています。例えばデータが６個入っていたら6個分の最後の画像が出力されてしまいます。$rowは数を返すんですよね？それぞれのデータを取得したいのですがうまくいきません

Comment: $rowはsql selectで指定されたカラムデータの配列が返されます。phpのスクリプトとSQLが、どの様に書かれているか見えないので、一番基本的な$stmt = $pdo->queryと  while文で単独で動かしてデバッグするのが良いと思います。